# Drop down menu appearing behind Web Page embedded using object tag

Tags: html, css, object, menu, drop-down-menu

I've been working on styling an intranet for the company I'm working for, and we've decided to adopt drop down menus for our global navigation.

We've identified an issue wherein pages embedded in object tags eclipse the drop down menus.
We do not have the option to change the behaviour of the pages embedded as objects as this is the chosen solution by which to display SAP pages within the intranet (iframes do not work for these pages according to the developers).

The drop down menus are crafted using purely css and html and are effectively absolutely positioned elements. I have tried setting an absolute position and z index on the object and menus however this has not worked.

Does anyone have a solution that would allow the drop down menus to appear over the web pages embedded via the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that works for all objects.

If you create an iframe with a z index of greater than 0 and position it over the object, it displays in front of the object. If you then position a div element with a z index greater than the iframe over the iframe, it displays clearly.

It is a little tricky to implement this with a drop down menu, but it is possible. Hope this helps someone else.